# Alternate power supply for dashcam, with latching relay

Tags: battery-operated, ups, latching-relay

I am trying to setup dashcam with a dedicated battery for my car, I have a crude diagram to explain my logic. Yet to figure out detailed specs.

The dashcam will run as usual car's ignition power, when the ignition is off the battery will take over. Unless the toggle switch is pressed which will cut off battery. (this is for long and safe parking).

I just want to check whether this scenario is feasible or not?

[image: UPS Dashcam]

I want to satisfy below cases.

**when the power is on and switch not pressed:**

- camera turns on automatically.
- battery backup is ready, charging happens.
- if the switch was on open state, reset back to closed state.

**when the power is on and switch pressed:**

- disconnect battery, no charging.
- camera still runs, until power is
  off.
- no action when button is pressed again.

**When power is off and switch not pressed:**

- if switch was open no action.
- if switch was closed camera runs from battery, until power is back on.

**when power is off and switch pressed:**

- if switch was open no action.
- if switch was closed, disconnect battery, pressed again no action.